# How to extract qualifying emails from sql export text?

Tags: php, regex, csv, email, preg-match-all

I've got a block of text like this:

```
(2843, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'mail@yahoo.gr', '', ''),
(2844, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'mail1@washpost.com', '', ''),
(2845, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'someMail@gmail.com', '', ''),
(2846, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'else@gmail.gov', '', ''),
```

How can I extract all email addresses that end with `.gov`?

I would like to have a string of comma-separated values as a result.  Something like this:

```
else@gmail.gov,nextElse@gmail.gov
```

Comment: PHP has function for handling csv's that would be your first step

Comment: That's not a CSV -- it's a MySQL dump.

Comment: values, separated by commas ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample input and your criteria, this will tell regex your intentions:

```
/[^']+\.gov(?=')/
```

Match all non-apostrophe characters followed by `.gov` followed by (not capturing) `'`.

Then implode the output array with commas.

Or fewer steps with:

```
/^(?:[^,]*, ){7}'\K[^']+\.gov(?=')/m
```

Pattern Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nmNjZb/1/

This will match more literally from the start of each line.

Code:  (Demo: https://3v4l.org/por3g )

```
$csv="(2843, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'mail@yahoo.gr', '', ''),
(2844, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'mail1@washpost.com', '', ''),
(2845, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'someMail@gmail.com', '', ''),
(2846, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'else@gmail.gov', '', ''),
(2846, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'nextElse@gmail.gov', '', '')";
echo implode(',',preg_match_all("/^(?:[^,]*, ){7}'\K[^']+\.gov(?=')/m",$csv,$out)?$out[0]:[]);
```

Output:

```
else@gmail.gov,nextElse@gmail.gov
```

Comment: @Andrzej You are welcome, but StackOverflow asks that you not use comments to say thanks. (You may delete your comment now).  Also, if you are wondering why you received downvotes -- it is because your question shows no proof of effort / research / attempt to self-solve.  StackOverflow must not be used as a free coding service.  I encourage you to improve this question if you can, take the StackOverflow tour to understand what is expected of you when you ask a question, and try to compose a complete, well-researched question when you encounter coding issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
  preg_match("/[\w.+\-]+@gmail\.gov/", $input, $output);
```

$output will have all matched emails. Then in PHP you can fetch using for loop and append comma between emails.

**EDIT**

```
$str = "(2843, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'mail@yahoo.gr', '', ''),
(2844, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'mail1@gmail.gov', '', ''),
(2845, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'someMail@gmail.gov', '', ''),
(2846, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'else@gmail.gov', '', '')";

preg_match_all("/[\w.+\-]+@gmail.gov/", $str, $output);

$final_str="";
foreach($output[0] as $email){
    $final_str .= $email.",";
}   
$final_str = rtrim($final_str,","); //Remove last comma
echo $final_str;
```

Output:
    `mail1@gmail.gov,someMail@gmail.gov,else@gmail.gov`

Comment: Works with the Example provided; somehow Crashes when a Large array is put --- below Answer solves it